# Quicksort confusion

Tags: java, quicksort

I'm going through the quicksort and whichever article i see, i get more confused.

1) This implementation is really good http://gauss.ececs.uc.edu/Courses/C321/html/quicksort.java.html

But as i understand, after each pass, the pivot index is in correct position.

Then ideally we should be doing the following:

```
   public static void Quicksort(int A[], int f, int l)
   {
      if (f >= l) return;
      int pivot_index = partition(A, f, l);
      Quicksort(A, f, pivot_index-1); //*** pivot_index-1
      Quicksort(A, pivot_index+1, l);
   }
```

But tutorial uses **Quicksort(A, f, pivot_index);**.

I'm 200% sure that making the change 'pivot_index-1' will not improve any performance or reduce the complexity; but just want to make if my understanding is correct.

2) The implementation [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaAlgorithmsQuicksort/article.html) works; but it doesn't place the pivot element at the correct position with each pass.

Comment: Have a look here http://xoax.net/comp_sci/crs/algorithms/lessons/Lesson4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two implementations I've seen:

- End index inclusive
- End index exclusive

`Quicksort(A, f, pivot_index-1);` is for the first case.

`Quicksort(A, f, pivot_index);` is for the second case.

Doing `Quicksort(A, f, pivot_index);` on the first case will still result in a sorted list, but will do a bit of extra work.

Doing `Quicksort(A, f, pivot_index-1);` on the second case **probably won't** result in a fully sorted list all the time.

**Analysis of [this implementation](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaAlgorithmsQuicksort/article.html):**

I can see why it works (it will swap the pivot with a greater element at a lower index), but that's not the QuickSort I know, and it might be doing slightly more work than required.

Comment: As i understand, the implementation on the first link is End index Inclusive; as it does the comparison as : while (A[l] > pivot) l--; So, in this case using 'Quicksort(A, f, pivot_index-1);' should work right?

Comment: The implementation on the first link appear to be rather broken (I tried compiling and testing it), but yes, it appears to be inclusive, so `Quicksort(A, f, pivot_index-1);` should work.